# Context Menu in TableView JAVAFX 2.1

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I want to add a context menu to the tableview, more specifically I want to display context menu on table rows on a right click.

I tried with this code

```
 final EventHandler click = new EventHandler() {
           public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

           }

                @Override
                public void handle(Event arg0) {
                }
     };
            final Context menu = new ContextMenu();
     MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Add Image");
     item.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
          public void handle(ActionEvent t) 
          {
           }
                @Override
                public void handle(Event arg0)
                {
                  //some code here   
          }});
     menu.getItems().addAll(item);
     EditingCell cellFactory = new EditingCell(click,menu); 
      TableColumn col = new TableColumn("column1");
     col.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

Above code is working correctly in JAVAFX 2.0, and I am getting a context menu on right click, How ever when I run my code with JAVAFX 2.1 Context menu doesnt work.

I tried to get context menu's showing property using  showingProperty() method and it is returning false in JAVAFX 2.1 and true in JAVAFX 2.0

Further I also tried making my custom cellfactory class and here is my code (I took it from official JAVAFX TreeView context menu example)

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TableCell<String,String> {

    private TextField textField;
    private ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();

    public TextFieldTreeCellImpl() {
        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Add Employee");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {

            }
        });
        setContextMenu(addMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        //setGraphic(getTableCell().getGraphic());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                //setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());



            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });  

    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

and I added this custom cellfactory as:

```
 final Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = 
new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
        return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
}

};
col.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

Still it is working fine in JAVAFX 2.0 but not in JAVAFX 2.1

Please help me, I am having a hard time ...

Comment: Is this a bug in JAVAFX 2.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both official `TreeView` and `TableView` tutorials are working fine with JavaFX 2.1. The problem is, you are mixing these code examples. You cannot return the `TreeCell` when the cell factory of the `TableColumn` needs `TableCell`. Simply follow the TableView tutorial alone only and replace the EditingCell with the following one that has contextMenu:

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    private TextField textField;
    private ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();

    public EditingCell() {
        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Print Me");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

            public void handle(Event t) {
                // Do something with current row
                Person curr = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                System.out.println(curr.getFirstName() + " " + curr.getLastName());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
                setContextMenu(addMenu);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {

        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: my EditingCell class already has the same implementation of context menu as suggested by you. but its pretty strange that still I am unable to get the desired effect

Comment: I have tested my code in JavaFX 2.1 and it is working as expected. Try with demo code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting no response even when using  setContextMenu() method.

However,this is how I solved the problem

I just registered a mouse event and showed the context menu at specified position (at mouse click)

```
this.setContextMenu(menu);
   this.getContextMenu().setAutoHide(true);

      EventHandler event = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
    if (me.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
  tableView.getContextMenu().show(tableView, me.getSceneX(), me.getSceneY());
    }
 }
};    
      this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,event);
```

Comment: if (me.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
   table.getContextMenu().show(table, me.getScreenX(), me.getScreenY());}

getScreen* instead of getScene*