# JavaFX: CellFactory/Cells vs. individual Nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question regarding the TreeView in JavaFX. I do not quite get the point of using the cellfactory.

Lets say I have the following Tree:

```
public void initialize(TreeView<String> treeView){
    treeView.setRoot(new TreeItem<String>("Root"));
    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("1"));
    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("2"));
    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("3"));
    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("4"));
}
```

And I want to add a Contextmenu to each of the items. I do the following:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>() {
     @Override
     public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> stringTreeView) {
             return new ContextMenuCell();
        }
    });
```

ContextMenuCell.java looks like this:

```
public class ContextMenuCell extends TreeCell<String> {

    public ContextMenuCell (){
        setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Test")));
    }
}
```

This will add a contextmenu to each of the cells, but the label of the Treeitems disappear. How can I make them stay or readd?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284503/context-menu-in-tableview-javafx-2-1?rq=1

Comment: I thank you for your comment, but I am not able to see, how the label of the node is published into the ContextMenuCell i return with the Callback. Can you help me see?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.7.0_45, Hendrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the updateItem method of TreeCell, that's where it gets drawn

```
private static final class ContextMenuCell extends TreeCell {

    ContextMenuCell() {
        setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Test")));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you brian. This code works. Would you be so kind and help me understand it?

1. I can see your class inherits from TreeCell and not TreeCell<String>.
What is the exact difference here?
2. Object item is the TreeItem of the current node?

Comment: IF you want TreeCell<String>, change to `@Override public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)`.  Then you don't have to call item.toString, java already knows it is.  2. Yes, I think the right way to get the item is getItem() and then do a null check.

Comment: Thank you again. I begin to understand now. But what still is unclear is the role of the Callback.
.setCellFactory(new Callback <TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>(){});

creates a Callback object with the stated types and the call method:

public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> stringTreeView){} carries out the Callback. And it returns the new ContextMenuCell we created in the answers above.

But how does the information of the cells (Label,...) get into the callback and eventually into ContextMenuCell. We access the information in the Object item object, so it has to be there somehow

Comment: TreeView asks for a cell when it needs one.  I haven't read the source code to see what happens in the background.  You can set all those properties in updateItem.  There's more you can override if you want to make it editable.