# How to completely reset a TreeView when changing the root when you have a CellFactory?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

That's the followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27894108/1093528)... FXML file reproduced here:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:id="pane"
    fx:controller="com.github.parboiled1.grappa.debugger.mainwindow.MainWindowUi">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                <MenuItem fx:id="loadInput" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Load file" onAction="#loadFileEvent"/>
                <MenuItem fx:id="parse" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Parse" onAction="#parseEvent"/>
                <MenuItem fx:id="closeButton" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Close" onAction="#closeWindowEvent"/>
            </Menu>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0"
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL">
                <TreeView fx:id="traceTree" prefHeight="200.0"
                    prefWidth="200.0" editable="false"/>
                <TextArea fx:id="traceDetail" prefHeight="200.0"
                    prefWidth="200.0"/>
            </SplitPane>
            <TextArea fx:id="inputText" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"/>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Since then I have change the type of the view, and I now have a `CellFactory` to generate cells and plug mouse click events. It works:

```
public final class ParseNodeCellFactory
    implements Callback<TreeView<MatchResult>, TreeCell<MatchResult>>
{
    private final MainWindowPresenter presenter;

    public ParseNodeCellFactory(final MainWindowPresenter presenter)
    {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeCell<MatchResult> call(final TreeView<MatchResult> param)
    {
        final ParsingTreeCell cell = new ParsingTreeCell();
        final EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler
            = event -> presenter.handleMatchResult(cell.getTreeItem());
        cell.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
        return cell;
    }

    private static final class ParsingTreeCell
        extends TreeCell<MatchResult>
    {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final MatchResult item, final boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty)
                setText(item.getLabel() + " ("
                    + (item.isSuccess() ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE") + ')');
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have two problems:

- when I expand/collapse parts of the tree, the given cells don't hide automatically;
- the `TreeView` must be completely reset on each run.

I don't know how to solve either of these problems...

Right now I have this code (`ui` is a reference to the JavaFX controller):

```
@Override
public void setParseTree(final TreeItem<MatchResult> root)
{
    clearTraceTree();
    ui.traceTree.setRoot(root);
}

private void clearTraceTree()
{
    final TreeItem<MatchResult> root = ui.traceTree.getRoot();
    if (root != null) {
        clearChildren(root);
        ui.traceTree.setRoot(null);
    }
}

private void clearChildren(final TreeItem<MatchResult> item)
{
    final ObservableList<TreeItem<MatchResult>> children
        = item.getChildren();

    children.forEach(this::clearChildren);
    children.clear();
}
```

While this clears the list, the problem is that the old cells, which I have expanded beforehand, are still visible; I want to completely scratch them, and clear the focus on any cell which currently has it. How to do that?

Also, how would I set the focus on the root cell when a new root is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TreeCell` doesn't handle the case of empty cells. So when you remove everything from the tree, your cells (which become empty) won't update. Similarly when you collapse nodes in the tree.

You need

```
private static final class ParsingTreeCell
    extends TreeCell<MatchResult>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(final MatchResult item, final boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getLabel() + " ("
                + (item.isSuccess() ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE") + ')');
        }
    }
}
```

To reset the tree, you probably only need to do

```
root.getChildren().clear();
```

Comment: Huuh, I so have a lot to learn :( To be really honest I'd never have imagined that an "empty" cell meant that it was hidden! In the meanwhile I did fix the code based on [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335830/javafx-cellfactory-cells-vs-individual-nodes); yours is similar except that it doesn't reset the `Graphic`... I'm so unknowledgeable with JavaFX that I don't even know whether this matters at all...

Comment: OK, you were right; I did only need to `root.getChildren().clear()`, and I didn't need to `.setGraphic()` at all. Strange that setting the text to `null` seems to "hide" the cell, but ohwell. Now, I have another question wrt a `TextArea` and the font used in it... Why do I feel that you'll be the one to jump in and answer it? :p Thanks a lot for your knowledge!

Comment: An empty cell is one that doesn't represent any data. (The `TreeView` fills any extra vertical space with empty cells.) In your case you never set the graphic of any of the cells, so there is no need to reset it. Finally, the `setText(...)` method handles `null` values gracefully, and just "displays no text". The cell is there, but no has no content. (You could still see it if you styled a border on it, for example...)